# Jquery mobile - How to make my link to open menu with list item of id that i want to visit?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-mobile

I dont know, how to finish my code. I have collapsible menu that is hidden from begining when i click on link it shows up menu with list items inside, one of these list items is list with my id, that i want to visit after i click on link.

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#nav').hide();
    $('.featured_footer').click(function(e){
      $('#nav').show();
      $('#nav h4 a').trigger('click');    
   });
});
```

HTML:

```
<div id="nav" data-role="collapsible" data-theme="b">
     <h4>Menu</h4>
     <div data-role="listview" data-inset="true">
          <div id="featured" data-role="collapsible">
              <h2>Featured</h2>
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Inspect</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS CM4D</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Intelligence (OEE)</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Quality Products</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Academy</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS Lean Six</a><br />
              <a href="http://www.example.com" target="_blank">ATS MES</a><br />
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
<a class="featured_footer" href="#featured"><h2>Featured</h2></a><br /> {* This is Link that should redirect to id="featured" *}
```

Comment: how is this smarty-related?

Comment: It is written in smarty check comment i put only 1/64 of my code.

Comment: "i am using smarty in my project" != "this problem is related to smarty"

Comment: You are right. I'am newbie here.

Comment: don't worry. It's just that i have "smarty" tag in my favourite list and i got sad that finally i saw a smarty question... unrelated to smarty. Welcome to this community! :)

Answer (score 0):

As the `a` element is not nested in `h4` you may need to try this

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#nav').hide();
      $('.featured_footer').click(function(e){
      $('#nav').show();
      $('#nav #featured a').trigger('click');    
  });
 });
```

**EDIT**:

If you simply want to trigger the click event, use this to scroll to the menu list

```
  $(document).ready(function() {
      $('#nav').hide();
      $('.featured_footer').click(function(e){
      $('#nav').show();
      $('#nav h4 a')[0].click();  
      window.scrollTop($('#featured').scrollTop()) 
      //or  window.scrollTop($('#featured').offset().top)  
  });
 });
```

Comment: Code works fine. I mean that click. Jquery mobile add a after h4. When u click that then it shows list items inside. I still don't know, How to visit id on my page, after it shows. It is hidden from begining.

Comment: So you want to visit all links in this list?

Comment: I want show user location where they should click in menu because that link is in footer, between is +- 2meters of text, menu is in header. I want to show him this part of code <div id="featured" data-role="collapsible"> with all links inside.

Comment: Trigger click function works fine as i wrote it. I mean it shows list inside menu. I just want to redirect user from footer to that part of code where id is featured. Sorry maybe my english is not so good. This is problem href="#featured" It stays in footer and should go to that element with that id.

Comment: `window.scrollTop($('#featured').scrollTop())` or `window.scrollTop($('#featured').offset().top)` note that the #featured must be positioned(add css `position:absolute` or `position:relative`).

Comment: if i write to my element only that css rule position:relative it will works ?

Comment: you also need to use `scrollTop`. Adding that css rule makes it possible to scroll

Comment: I'm lost in this, scrollTop css rule wtf, how should i use it give example please ? You mean overflow: scroll or what ?

Comment: I found solution. Zhank you for your time and effort.